# I am getting a resource leak : fin error when the code worked previously

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, cygwin

I've read a few threads that said I should close a certain file when this error pops up when I use cppcheck. But my issue is this:

2 weeks back I ran a shell script which called another file inside it to execute and it worked fine.
But for the past two days, I got segmentation fault in when running the main code using Cygwin. I had posted about it earlier, and then on analysing the executable file (in cpp) using cppcheck, I got a line 31 resource leak : fin.

This particular block of code is pasted:

```
void load_fasta_list(char * file_name, vector<string> &file_list){
FILE * fin;
fin = fopen(file_name, "rt");
char temp_file[512];
char * temp_file2;
while (!feof(fin)){
    fgets(temp_file, 512, fin);   
    if (!feof(fin)){
        temp_file2 = strtok(temp_file, "\n");
        file_list.push_back(temp_file2);
    }
}
cout<<file_list.size()<<" FASTA files to be analyzed."<<endl;
```

}

The line 31 is the last bracket there.
These codes are available from Washington U which I am using (and I am a beginner), and I am getting this error without having done anything to the set of codes.

Any idea on how to progress?

P.S. When I tried the fclose statement, cppcheck showed no error, but when I ran the shell script again, I got the segmentation fault

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your lecturer taught you C instead of C++. He used a primitive C construct to open a file which must be manually closed instead of the automatic cleanup offered by C++. He forgot to do so, aptly demonstrating why using such constructs is inherently unsafe. It is also exception-unsafe, and there are other unpleasant potential bugs lurking in here such as off-by-one errors, and the *fun* which is non-reentrant strtok, due to the use of C string handling.

You should rewrite it (or make your lecturer fix it) to use the equivalent C++ constructs, which automatically clean up all the memory and file handles needed.

The code contains other offences too, like the output parameter, `using namespace std;`, and such. Whoever wrote it is simply unfit to teach C++. You need to kick them into gear.

Answer (score -1):

To prevent a leak, call

```
fclose(fin);
```

This call will close the file.

Answer (score -1):

I see two problems:

1. Check to see that fin is valid (fopen returns a null if the file doesn't exist!)
2. Use fclose(fin) to close your file